# Run parallel job without hyperthreading Torque PBS script

Tags: mpi, openmp, hpc, pbs, torque

Is it possible to disable Hyperthreading? Or a way via torque PBS script to use only physical cores available in the node.

My problem is when I run my MPI job with node=1:ppn=12 it runs with a good speed.(1st iteration take less than 1min) but when I use node=2:ppn=12 the speed is horrible (1st iteration takes more than 6hrs)

## My Torque PBS JOB SCRIPT

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #PBS -N Vcrlx
  #PBS -q batch
  #PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=12
  #PBS -l walltime=20:00:00
  #PBS -m bea
  #PBS -j oe 
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

mpirun -np 24 pw.x  < vcrlx.in > vcrlx.out
```

## Tried solutions

I emailed them about this Hyperthreading problem but no response yet (10days)

As my code [Quantum Espresso](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/) can run with MPI, OpenMP and with Mixed MPI+OpenMP. I tried my best to understand all these but failed to get desired results. Or maybe I misunderstood because of very poor background knowledge of these things.

I tried many combinations like following but none of them worked

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #PBS -N Vcrlx
  #PBS -q batch
  #PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=12::mpiprocs=1:ompthreads=24  <--------------
  #PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
  #PBS -m abe 
  #PBS -j oe 
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

mpirun -np 24 pw.x  < vcrlx.in > vcrlx.out
```

**its output**

```
     Parallel version (MPI & OpenMP), running on      48 processor cores
     Number of MPI processes:                24
     Threads/MPI process:                     2

     MPI processes distributed on     2 nodes
     R & G space division:  proc/nbgrp/npool/nimage =      24
```

**Please help me to run the job without Hyperthreading. Thanks**

Comment: Why do you blame hyper threading rather than inter-node communication? Don't the single node run uses 12 MPI processes and 2 Threads/MPI processes? Try `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` before `mpiexec` and see it you end up with only 1 Thread per MPI process.

Comment: I agree with @GillesGouaillardet based on the among of time that is taken the problems seems to be in MPI side. If in one node with hyper threading you don't have issues why would the hyper threading be the problem with two nodes? the number of nodes was the variable that has changed

Comment: Yes its MPI communication that is taking too long, not the Hyperthreading. 
I have 24hrs wall time, and I am running this job from more than 5days (I restart the job after 24hrs), so can you suggest me is it wise to go for multiple nodes or do I stick with 1node?

Comment: At first I would try one MPI tasks per socket. Assuming your nodes are dual socket with 6 cores per socket, a 2 nodes job would be 4 MPI tasks and 6 OpenMP threads per MPI task. What kind of interconnect are you using? Infiniband ? TCP/IP ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It is **InfiniBand**. And from your above suggestion is it `#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=4` and `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6`. If not then please explain in the script form. I may misunderstand things as a noob:(

Comment: That is right !